# Order dataframe by conditions combining many columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have two advanced sorting scenarios.

They are independent cases so I have listed below a sample with expected results.

```py
import pandas as pd

a={
  "ip":['10.10.11.30','10.10.11.30','10.10.11.30', '10.2.2.10', '10.10.2.1', '10.2.2.2'],
  "path":['/data/foo/err','/data/foo/zone','/data/foo/err','/data/foo/zone','/data/foo/zone','/data/foo/tmp'],
  "date":['25/01/2024','25/01/2024','01/08/2020','23/01/2024','24/01/2024','25/01/2024'],
  "count":[3,10,20,5,20,50]
}
df=pd.DataFrame(a)

print(df)
print()

## Output
            ip            path         date  count
0  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err   25/01/2024      3
1  10.10.11.30  /data/foo/zone   25/01/2024     10
2  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err   01/08/2020     20
3    10.2.2.10  /data/foo/zone   23/01/2024      5
4    10.10.2.1  /data/foo/zone   24/01/2024     20
5     10.2.2.2   /data/foo/tmp   25/01/2024     50
```

Runnable sample: https://onecompiler.com/python/422hhyqa5

### Sorting case 1

#### Rule(s)

- Order by ip ASC, date ASC, count ASC

#### Expected output

```py
            ip            path         date  count
5     10.2.2.2   /data/foo/tmp   25/01/2024     50
3    10.2.2.10  /data/foo/zone   23/01/2024      5
4    10.10.2.1  /data/foo/zone   24/01/2024     20
2  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err   01/08/2020     20
0  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err   25/01/2024      3
1  10.10.11.30  /data/foo/zone   25/01/2024     10
```

#### My Attempt

Performing "natural" sorting on multiple columns is straight forward (date is of type DateTime).

I also managed to achieve sorting by ip.

But I did not manage to combine the two as it always gives different errors

```py
df_sorted_by_date = (df.sort_values(by=['date', 'count'],
                    ascending=[True, True],
                    ignore_index=True)
df_sorted_by_ip = (df.sort_values(by=["ip"], 
                     key=lambda x: x.str.split(".").apply(lambda y: [int(z) for z in y]),
                     ignore_index=True))
```

### Sorting case 2

#### Rule(s)

- `rank1`: if `(path contains 'zone') and (count >=10)` then place 1st and order by `IP ASC`
- `rank2`: if `(path NOT contains 'zone') and (count >=10) and (date = today())` then place 2nd and order by `IP ASC`
- `rank3`: The remaining rows are placed last and ordered by `IP ASC` then `date ASC` if equal values

#### Expected output

let's assume today is 25th

```py
            ip            path         date  count
4    10.10.2.1  /data/foo/zone   24/01/2024     20   # rank1
1  10.10.11.30  /data/foo/zone   25/01/2024     10   # rank1
5     10.2.2.2   /data/foo/tmp   25/01/2024     50   # rank2
3    10.2.2.10  /data/foo/zone   23/01/2024      5   # rank3
2  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err   01/08/2020     20   # rank3
0  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err   25/01/2024      3   # rank3
```

#### My Attempt

None. I am not sure how to proceed, this is very advanced for me >_<

Comment: Note that your `date` values are in `dd/mm/yyyy` so you *cannot* sort them alphabetically as `01/02/2024` would be before `02/01/2024`

Comment: I converted them to datetime. So they are being sorted properly as dates, not strings. Which is what I want. Updated description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### case 1

Perform natural sorted with [`natsort`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
# pip install natsort
from natsort import natsort_key

# ensure datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

# sort in desired order
out = df.sort_values(by=['ip', 'date', 'count'], key=natsort_key)
```

Output:

```
            ip            path       date  count
5     10.2.2.2   /data/foo/tmp 2024-01-25     50
3    10.2.2.10  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-23      5
4    10.10.2.1  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-24     20
2  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err 2020-08-01     20
0  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err 2024-01-25      3
1  10.10.11.30  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-25     10
```

##### case 2

Assign your rank computed with [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and perform natural sorted with [`natsort`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
# pip install natsort
from natsort import natsort_key

# ensure datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

# conditions
m1 = df['path'].str.contains('zone')
m2 = df['count'].ge(10)
m3 = df['date'].eq(pd.Timestamp('25/01/2024')) # or 'today' in your case

# create rank based on your conditions
df['rank'] = np.select([m1&m2, m2&m3&~m1],
                       ['rank1', 'rank2'],
                       'rank3')

# sort in desired order
out = df.sort_values(by=['rank', 'ip', 'date', 'count'], key=natsort_key)
```

*NB. if needed, you can always `drop` the rank afterwards.*

Output:

```
            ip            path       date  count   rank
4    10.10.2.1  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-24     20  rank1
1  10.10.11.30  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-25     10  rank1
5     10.2.2.2   /data/foo/tmp 2024-01-25     50  rank2
3    10.2.2.10  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-23      5  rank3
2  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err 2020-08-01     20  rank3
0  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err 2024-01-25      3  rank3
```

##### handling NaT (bug?)

`natsort` seems to replace the missing values by -inf, which doesn't compare to timestamps. A workaround could be to use your own wrapper:

```
import numpy as np

def mykey(s):
    if np.issubdtype(s.dtype, np.datetime64):
        return s
    else:
        return natsort_key(s)

out = df.sort_values(by=['ip', 'date', 'count'], key=mykey)
```

Output:

```
            ip            path       date  count
5     10.2.2.2   /data/foo/tmp 2024-01-25     50
6     10.2.2.2   /data/foo/tmp        NaT     50
3    10.2.2.10  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-23      5
4    10.10.2.1  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-24     20
2  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err 2020-08-01     20
0  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err 2024-01-25      3
1  10.10.11.30  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-25     10
```

or to convert the dates to integers:

```
out = df.loc[df.astype({'date': int}).sort_values(by=['ip', 'date', 'count'], key=natsort_key).index]
```

Output:

```
            ip            path       date  count
6     10.2.2.2   /data/foo/tmp        NaT     50
5     10.2.2.2   /data/foo/tmp 2024-01-25     50
3    10.2.2.10  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-23      5
4    10.10.2.1  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-24     20
2  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err 2020-08-01     20
0  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err 2024-01-25      3
1  10.10.11.30  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-25     10
```

Comment: @Onyambu yes it will, thanks to `natsort`.

Comment: Check the first two rows in the output for instance. `10.10.2.1` is before `10.10.11.30` as expected.

Comment: I like this solution with `natsort`. Also makes it easier to generalize for other cases. Can you please add the (simple) first case as well so I can accept the answer.

Comment: @Enissay it's the same without the rank, but as this makes things more explicit I updated the anwer

Comment: Yes, already deducted it from your answer already. Just to be fair vis-a-vis the other reply. Thank you again, I have refactored a good part of my code to take advantage of this clear way of sorting.

Comment: I applied the solution to a larger dataset which has some dates missing. When trying to order like above, it gives `TypeError: 'values' is not ordered, please explicitly specify the categories order by passing in a categories argument.`

Comment: @Enissay that seems to be a bug of `natsort`. It looks like it replaces the NaT by `-inf`, which is not a valid value for comparison with a timestamp. You might want to report it

Comment: I added a workaround

Comment: Thank you, It all works. I also posted a bug fix request: https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort/issues/170

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to report the issue! I'm looking forward to a fix.

Comment: Sorry I keep asking follow-up questions as I keep finding edge cases xD. Let's say I want to sort by `path`, and one of the values is empty. Using the same code, the empty value always placed first! I didn't manage to put it last :x E.g.: `df.sort_values(by=['path'], key=workaround_natsort_key, na_position="last")`

Answer (score 1):

first convert your `date` and `ip` columns then do the sorting as shown:

```
from ipaddress import ip_address

df['ip'] = df['ip'].map(ip_address)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst = True)
```

#### Sorting Case 1:

```
df.sort_values(['ip', 'date','count'])

            ip            path       date  count
5     10.2.2.2   /data/foo/tmp 2024-01-25     50
3    10.2.2.10  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-23      5
4    10.10.2.1  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-24     20
2  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err 2020-08-01     20
0  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err 2024-01-25      3
1  10.10.11.30  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-25     10
```

#### Sorting Case 2:

```
count = df['count'].ge(10)
zone = df.path.str.contains('zone')
today = df['date'].eq(pd.Timestamp('25/01/2024'))

df['rank1'] = ~(zone & count)
df['rank2'] = ~( ~zone & count & today)

(df.sort_values(['rank1','rank2', 'ip', 'date'])
  .drop(columns=['rank1', 'rank2']))

            ip            path       date  count
4    10.10.2.1  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-24     20
1  10.10.11.30  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-25     10
5     10.2.2.2   /data/foo/tmp 2024-01-25     50
3    10.2.2.10  /data/foo/zone 2024-01-23      5
2  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err 2020-08-01     20
0  10.10.11.30   /data/foo/err 2024-01-25      3
```

Comment: In the end, this looks like a very similar logic to mine except using multiple intermediate columns ;) You might want to make it explicit that this approach mutates the `ip` column into a `Version` object (btw, using `ipadress.ip_adress` would have been a better choice IMO, since this is actually an ip adress and not a version number).